# .htaccess root changed with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, root

So i'm trying to rewrite the URL like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Works perfectly but relative paths to JavaScript and CSS get messed up.

Shouldn't the line below exclude files ?

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` makes sure existing files are not rewritten hence images/css/js files won't be routed to `index.php`.

However your problem seems to be use of relative paths for images/css/js. Make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Otherwise** you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.